# Calculate the first cohomoly group of a sheaf of quotients in Macaulay2

Tags: macaulay2, algebraic-number

I want to calculate the cohomology of the sheaf Q in the exact sequence on $\mathbb P^3$:

> `0\rightarrow\mathcal O(-1)\rightarrow \mathcal O^{\oplus 4}\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 0`

To do it, I want to calculate the cohomology of Q, using Macaulay2.

I write the follow (using the tutorial in [CoherentSheaf](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.17/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/___Coherent__Sheaf_sp_sl_sp__Coherent__Sheaf.html))

```
X=Proj(QQ[x,y,z,w])
A=OO_X^4
B=OO_X^1 (-1)
C=A/B
```

But, in the four line the output say:

> `C=A/B`
> `stdio:15:3:(3): error: expected modules with the same ambient module.`

I'm having trouble writing the correct code using Macaulay2. I'm following the tutorial (linked above), but I keep getting an error message. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted gives a 404 error.
The error you encountered in Macaulay2 is due to the mismatch in the ambient module of the two modules A and B that you are trying to compute the quotient of. To fix this error, you need to ensure that the ambient modules of A and B are the same.

```
i1 : X = Proj(QQ[x, y, z, w])

o1 = X

o1 : ProjectiveVariety

i2 : A = OO_X^4

        4
o2 = OO
       X

o2 : coherent sheaf on X, free

i3 : B = OO_X^4

        4
o3 = OO
       X

o3 : coherent sheaf on X, free

i4 : C = A/B

o4 = cokernel | 1 0 0 0 |
              | 0 1 0 0 |
              | 0 0 1 0 |
              | 0 0 0 1 |

                                         4
o4 : coherent sheaf on X, quotient of OO  
                                        X
```

p.s: For Macaulay2 questions, I recommend you to ask in [its own Google group.](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/macaulay2/)

Comment: The link to the Macaulay2 page for the CoherentSheaf package is CoherentSheaf/CoherentSheaf. I have visited the page and found it to be informative without any difficulties. However, in my specific case, I need to calculate the quotient using the module O_X(-1), whereas in your example, you used the module O_X^4. Thank you for providing the answer. I will visit the link you shared.

Comment: @Protágoras Yes, I saw it now, but at that time it was giving 404, maybe it was a temporary problem and it has been solved. And yes, now that I saw the page, I realized that what I wrote was not what you meant. I don't remember much about cohomology but asked in the Google group I linked before, and you will get an answer. Whatever I saw, Dr. Grayson or others always answered to questions there.